# startBuyPageActivity in inAppBilling in android

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, in-app-billing

I'm new to android and because of that I need your help. Thanks in advance!!! I'm trying to implement in app billing in my app, but one thing isn't clear to me...i looked into developer.android.com and search through google, but didn't find why is so importent to implement in startBuyPageActivity which is in PurchaseObserver.java file in the sample application method for Android 2.0 and above and how to do it... I ask you this because i have 2.2 android phone for testing and i testing with android.test.purchased product and everything is good...i get that item is purchased and it appears on my activity... Every bit of help or information is appreciated...
Thanks again for a help or information...  :D
This is my startBuyPageActivity code:

```
private static void startBuyPageActivity(PendingIntent pendingIntent, Intent intent, Context context){
try {
                pendingIntent.send(context, 0, intent); 
                String i = null;
            } catch (CanceledException e){
                Log.e(TAG, "startBuyPageActivity CanceledException");
            }
}
```

Comment: Are there somebody that can help me???